# Saving JSON to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to save data retrieved from API to a `DataTable`. JSON which is returned from API can't be deserialized directly to `DataTable` using this code:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

I got an error: `Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable.` I read that it's beacuse JSON format is not as it should be. Mine is as follows:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "page_size": 1000,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "e1b019b9a8bf408c9cb964c29e845104",
      "asset_id": "5adb0d87882b4e14b99bde74a967e84c",
      "alias": "Concrete Pump Yellow",
      "serial_number": "QEQ000123",
      "model": {
        "name": "Pump C50-HP"
      },
      "operating_hours": {
        "hours": 100,
        "unit_driven": true
      }
   }
  ]
}
```

I know I need format like `[{..}]` but can't find workaround, API returns JSON as above. I can deserialize it using this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

but how can I now add data to `DataTable`? I'm looking for a solution for it

Comment: Why do you need to save this data to a DataTable? What are you going to do with that DataTable?

Comment: I want to insert data to database using DataTable

Comment: Why do you need a DataTable to do that? You're likely making it more difficult on yourself by introducing arbitrary requirements like this.

Comment: The issue is that I'm looking for a way to insert data from API directly to database. I thought that first I needed to store data in some table (e.g. DataTable) and iterate through it to save data to database row by row. If DT is not an option then what's the best solution?

Comment: A DataTable is an option. It's just not a good one. Instead, you can deserialize to custom objects (RoryF's answer shows how to do that) and then you can iterate through the objects that you've deserialized to, and run SQL INSERT commands based on those objects, perhaps using a micro-ORM such as [Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/). The only reason you'd need a DataTable for this would be if you needed to use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is that the json you're deserializing is not a DataTable, its just an Object.

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request, typeof(Object)) -> Where Object would be a defined Class with parameter definitions to deserialize the json to, i.e page, page_size, id etc..

Once in this format its fairly easy to coerce it into a DataTable:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0

The Classes would look something along the lines of:

```
public class Items
{
    public Guid? Id {get;set;}
    public Guid? AssetId {get;set;}
    public string alias {get;set;}
    public string serial_number {get;set;}
    public Model model {get;set;}
    public OperatingHours operatingHours {get;set;}
}
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get;set;}
}
public class OperatingHours
{
    public int Hours {get;set;}
    public bool Unit_Driven {get;set;}
}
public class OverallObject
{
    public int Page {get;set;}
    public int PageSize {get;set;}
    public List<Items> AllItems {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This seems like a great explanation of problem and the solution, but where is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

What the `JsonConvert` class does is it materializes your `string` version of the response into an `object`. For this to work, your `string` version has to match the structure of the resulting `object` or the class needs hints to know how to inflate the object. The runtime is telling you that there is a mismatch and it doesn't know how to resolve it.

There are a few ways to get this done. I prefer an structured approach so I would recommend you create classes to receive the data:

```
var payload = @"{
                      ""page"": 1,
                      ""page_size"": 1000,
                      ""items"": [
                        {
                          ""id"": ""e1b019b9a8bf408c9cb964c29e845104"",
                          ""asset_id"": ""5adb0d87882b4e14b99bde74a967e84c"",
                          ""alias"": ""Concrete Pump Yellow"",
                          ""serial_number"": ""QEQ000123"",
                          ""model"": {
                            ""name"": ""Pump C50-HP""
                          },
                          ""operating_hours"": {
                            ""hours"": 100,
                            ""unit_driven"": true
                          }
                       }
                      ]
                    }";

public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("page")]
    public int Page { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("page_size")]
    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public IEnumerable<ApiResponseItem> Items { get; set; }

}

public class ApiResponseItem
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]        
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("asset_id")]
    public string AssetId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alias")]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("serial_number")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("model")]
    public ApiResponseModel Model { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("operating_hours")]
    public ApiResponseOperatingHours OperatingHours { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponseModel
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponseOperatingHours
{
    [JsonProperty("hours")]
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("unit_driven")]
    public bool UnitDriven { get; set; }
}

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(payload);
```

As you can see, the classes use hint attributes to let the deserializer know about the fields. You can then loop through the `response.Items` enumerable and consume the items as desired.

**UPDATE:**

For posterity and at the suggestion of @mason, it's important to point out that there is no need to use a `DataTable`. A quick inspection of the payload reveals the output is a paged version of set of records so it's not equivalent to a data table.

Comment: @mason The `DataTable` is irrelevant because the **real issue** is that the OP does not understand how serialization works. A quick inspection of the payload reveals the output is a paged version of set of records so it's not equivalent to a data table.
Addressing the true issue opens the door for him to choose the right approach **after** the data has been inflated. There is zero need to use a convoluted, overly complex set of data objects when the goal is to just save the output of a nested collection.
A moot point as another answer with a similar approach was accepted.